# What defines robust code?

Tags: terminology, standards, defensive-programming

My professor keeps referring to this Java example when he speaks of "robust" code:

```
if (var == true) {
    ...
} else if (var == false) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

He claims that "robust code" means that your program takes into account all possibilities, and that there is no such thing as an error - all situations are handled by the code and result in valid state, hence the "else".

I am doubtful, however. If the variable is a boolean, what is the point of checking a third state when a third state is logically impossible?

"Having no such thing as an error" seems ridiculous as well; even Google applications show errors directly to the user instead of swallowing them up silently or somehow considering them as valid state. And it's good - I like knowing when something goes wrong. And it seems quite the claim to say an application would never have any errors.

So what is the *actual* definition of "robust code"?

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx

Comment: This would only hold in a not-strongly-typed language. In a strongly typed language a variable of type boolean (not some integer posing as a boolean), can only be true or false, there is no third option...

Comment: There was another question, [what is elegant code](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/97912/how-do-you-define-elegant-code), which got closed as a duplicate of "what is good code" -- a rather presumptuous decision, I think, but this question's likely to be closed as well. This question should demonstrate that there are multiple aspects to what constitutes "good code", so there's no sense closing either this question or the question about elegant code.

Comment: ask him how would you test coverage on the 3rd case, because robust code should surely require testing, and if you don't manage to test the 3rd case, you wouldn't be able to find any bugs that might lurk in there.

Comment: @Marjan - in a not-strongly-typed language one would most likely just write: if (var) { } else { }

Comment: @kevin: yes, functionally that may work pretty well. However, it is sweeping things under the carpet and it may come back and bite you elsewhere. For example when you mix `if (var) { } else { }` and `if not (var) { } else { }` for the same variable. Of course that may depend on how the language interprets the values that aren't true or false.

Comment: I do not know of any languages where both x and !x could be true.  Note that I didn't suggest "if (x == true) ..."; I abhor such comparisons.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing robust code vs. overengineering](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/110227/writing-robust-code-vs-overengineering)

Comment: To echo @kevincline, the only situation I know of where `(x == y)` and `(x != y)` could be both `false` is that both `x` and `y` are floating point numbers, and that one or both values are `NaN`. Good job, IEEE. (As expected, some C++ compilers have an option to ignore this behavior. However, most floating-point source code "out there" can be broken by injecting `NaN`s, whether this switch is set to on or off.)

Comment: Since your professor makes this statement, I'm thinking he's talking about principles and not this very specific example. You are supposed to induce the principle and it's simple from the example.

There are cases you haven't thought of, as in the example, and you have to have  some sort of mitigating code. This is also a possible definition of what robust code is.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> what is the point of checking a third state when a third state is
>   logically impossible?

What about a `Boolean?` that allows for a `NULL` state that is neither true nor false.  Now what should the software do?  Some software has to be highly crash-resistant like pacemakers.  Ever seen someone add a column to a database that was a `Boolean` and initialize the current data to `NULL` initially?  I know I've seen it.

Here are a few links that discuss what it means to be robust in terms of software:

- [Robust Programming](http://nob.cs.ucdavis.edu/bishop/secprog/robust.html)
- [Robust Definition](http://www.linfo.org/robust.html)
- [Robustness, the forgotten code quality.](https://web.archive.org/web/20180217231754/http://www.makinggoodsoftware.com/2010/03/02/robustness-the-forgotten-code-quality/)
- [How to write robust code](http://www.iovene.com/posts/2007/01/how-to-write-robust-code/)

If you think there is one universally agreed upon definition of "robust" here, good luck.  There can be some synonyms like bomb-proof or idiot-proof.  [The Duct Tape Programmer](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2009/09/23.html) would be an example of someone that usually writes robust code at least in my understanding of the terms.

Comment: If this was a nullable boolean both Java and c# would throw so null should be checked first.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any universally agreed upon definition of what a cat or a dog are.

Comment: Swift would say nil is not true, and nil is not false either. (You can compare optionals or optional and non-optional, and nil == nil, nil != anything else, anything else != nil).

Answer (score 11):

For the sake of my discussion a Bool can have 2 states, True or False. Anything else is non-conformance to the programming langugae specification. If your tool chain is non-conformant to its specification, you are hosed no matter what you do. 
If a developer created a type of Bool that had more than 2 states, it's the last thing he would ever do on my codebase.

Option A.

```
if (var == true) {
    ...
} else if (var == false) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Option B

```
if (var == true) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

I assert Option B is more robust.....

Any twit can tell you to handle unexpected errors. They are usually trivally easy to detect once you think of them. The example your professior has given is not something that could happen, so it's a very poor example.

A is impossible to test without convoluted test harnesses. If you can't create it, how are you going to test it? If you have not tested the code, how do you know it works? If you don't know it works, then you are not writing robust software. I think they still call that a Catch22 (Great movie, watch it sometime).

Option B is trivial to test.

Next problem, ask you professor this question "What do you want me to do it about it if a Boolean is neither True nor False?" 
That should lead into an a very interesting discussion.....

Most cases, a core dump is approriate, at worst it annoys the user or costs a lot of money.  What if, say, the module is the Space shuttle realtime reentry calculation system? Any answer, no matter how inaccurate, cannot be worse than aborting, which will kill the users. So what to do, if you know the answer might be wrong, go for the 50/50, or abort and go fo the 100% failure. If I was a crew member, I'd take the 50/50.

Option A kills me
Option B gives me an even chance of survival.

But wait - it's a simulation of the space shuttle reentry - then what? Abort so you know about it. Sound like a good idea? - NOT - because you need to test with the code you plan to ship.

Option A is better for simluation, but can't be deployed. It's useless
Option B is the deployed code so the simulation performs the same as the live systems.

Let's say this was a valid concern. The better solution would be to isolate the error handling from the application logic.

```
if (var != true || var != false) {
    errorReport("Hell just froze over, var must be true or false")
}
......
if (var == true){
 .... 
} else {
 .... 
}
```

[Futher reading](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nachumd/verify/horror.html) - Therac-25 Xray machine, Ariane 5 Rocket failure and others
(Link has many broken links but enough info that Google will help)

Comment: "..unexpected errors. They are usually trivally easy to detect once you think of them" - but when you think of them, they're no longer unexpected.

Comment: There is [some question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/69478) as to if your code `if (var != true || var != false) {` should be an `&&` instead.

Comment: I can easily think of a bool that is neither true or false, but it's still unexpected. In case you say a bool cannot be anything else, if I check whether a letter is a digit character and then convert it to its integer value, I can easily think of that integer value being less than 0 or greater than 9, but it's still unexpected.

Comment: Null Booleans are supported in Java and C#, and have a real-world application. Consider a database containing a list of people. After a while you decide you need a gender (isMale) field. Null means "never asked so don't know"; true means male and false means female. (OK, trans-gender omitted for simplicity...).

Comment: @kiwiron: Would a better solution not be to use a enumeration type, "Male", "Female", "Did Not Ask". Enumerations are better - can be extended when the need arises ( in your e.g. Asexual, Hermaphrodite, "Refused to  Answer" come to mind).

Comment: In some languages `if (var <> false)` is more robust because there false is defined as 0 and true is every think else. I have seen this in visual basic, assembler and c

Comment: @k3b - that why I qualified my answer in the opening sentence.

Answer (score 9):

Actually your code is not more robust but LESS robust. The final `else` is simply dead code that you can't test.

In critical software such as in spacecrafts, dead code and more generally untested code is forbidden: If a cosmic ray produces a single event upset that in turn makes your dead code being activated, anything is possible. If the SEU activates a portion of robust code, the (unexpected) behaviour stays under control.

Comment: I dont get it in spacecrafts is dead code forbidden? i.e. you cant write the last else? since you cant test it you cant put it in?

but then what does it mean "If the SEU activates a portion of robust code, the (unexpected) behaviour stays under control."

Comment: Yes, in space critical software test coverage must be 100% and as a consequence unreachable code (aka dead code) is forbidden.

Answer (score 7):

I think the professor might be confusing "error" and "bug". Robust code should certainly have few/no bugs. Robust code may, and in a hostile environment, must, have good error management (be it exception handling or rigorous return status tests).

I agree that the professor's code example is silly, but not as silly as mine.

```
// Assign 3 to x
var x = 3;
x = 3;   // again, just for sure
while (x < 3 or x > 3) { x = 3; }  // being robust
if (x != 3) { ... }  // this got to be an error!
```

Comment: The last if certainly be triggered, it wouldn't require really that much effort. Any experienced C programmer have seen values suddenly change. Of course logically, in a controlled single-threaded environment, this should never happen. In real life, the code inside the if will eventually happen. If there's nothing useful you can do inside that if, then don't code it! (I had a funny experience during a particular software development where I raised an exception with curse words in case something impossible happened... guess what happened?).

Comment: True story: `boolean x = something(); if (x) { x = True // make sure it's really true, ... }`

Answer (score 6):

There is no agreed upon definition of *Robust Code*, as for many things in programming it's more or less subjective...

The example your professor gives depends on the language:

- In Haskell, a `Boolean` can be either `True` or `False`, there is no third option
- In C++, a `bool` can be `true`, `false`, or (unfortunately) come from some dubious cast that put it in an unknown case... This *should* not happen, but may, as a result of a previous error.

However, what your professor is advising obscures the code by introducing extraneous logic for *should-not-happen* events in the middle of the core program, so I will point you, instead, toward [Defensive Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming).

In university case, you could even augment it by adopting a Design By Contract strategy:

- Establish invariants for classes (eg, `size` is the number of items in the `data` list)
- Establish pre-conditions and post-conditions for each function (e.g., this function may only be invoked with `a` being less than `10`)
- *Test* each of those at the entry and exit points of each of your functions

Example:

```
class List:
  def __init__(self, items):
    self.__size = len(items)
    self.__data = items

  def __invariant(self):
    assert self.__size == len(self.__data)

  def size(self):
    self.__invariant()

    return self.__size

  def at(self, index):
    """index should be in [0,size)"""
    self.__invariant()
    assert index >= 0 and index < self.__size

    return self.__data[index]

  def pushback(self, item):
    """the subsequent list is one item longer
       the item can be retrieved by self.at(self.size()-1)"""
    self.__invariant()

    self.__data.append(item)
    self.__size += 1

    self.__invariant()
    assert self.at(self.size()-1) == item
```

Comment: But the professor specifically said that it was Java, and specifically did NOT say what the type of var is. If it is Boolean, it can be true, false, or null. If something else, it can be unequal to both true and unequal to false. Yes, overlap between robust, defensive, and paranoid.

Comment: In C, C++ and Objective-C, a bool can have an indeterminate value, like any other type, but any assignment will set it to true or false and nothing else. For example: bool b = 0; b++; b++; will set b to true.

Comment: @gnasher729 not an indeterminate value, accessing an uninitialized value means your *whole program's* behaviour is undefined, including the parts that happen before the access.

Answer (score 2):

Your professor's approach is totally misguided.

A function, or just a bit of code, should have a spec that says what it does, which should cover every possible input. And the code should be written so that its behaviour is guaranteed to match the spec. In the example, I would write the spec quite simple like this:

```
Spec: If var is false then the function does "this", otherwise it does "that".
```

Then you write the function:

```
if (var == false) dothis; else dothat;
```

and the code meets the spec. So your professor says: What if var == 42? Look at the spec: It says the function should do "that". Look at the code: The function does "that". The function meets the spec.

Where your professor's code makes things totally unrobust is the fact that with his approach, when var is neither true nor false, it will execute code that has never been called before and that is completely untested, with utterly unpredictable results.

Answer (score 1):

Robust code is simply code that handles failures well.  No more, no less.

Of failures, there are many types: incorrect code, incomplete code, unexpected values, unexpected states, exceptions, resource exhaustion, ....  Robust code handles these well.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [@gnasher729 's statement: ***Your professor's approach is totally misguided.***](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/284104/421032)

Robust means it's resistant to breakage/failure because it makes few assumptions and is decoupled: it's self contained, self defining, and portable. It also includes being adaptable to changing requirements. In a word, your code is **durable**.

This generally translates into short functions that get their data from parameters passed in by the caller, and the use of public interfaces for consumers - abstract methods, wrappers, indirection, COM style interfaces, etc - rather than functions containing concrete implementation code.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the code you gave as an example of **defensive programming** (at least as I use the term). Part of defensive programming is to make choices that minimise assumptions made about the behaviour of the rest of the system.  For example, which of these is better:

```
for (int i = 0; i != sequence.length(); ++i) {
    // do something with sequence[i]
}
```

Or:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length(); ++i) {
    // do something with sequence[i]
}
```

(In case you're having trouble seeing the difference, check the loop test: the first uses `!=`, the second uses `<`).

Now, under most circumstances, the two loops will behave in exactly the same way. However, the first (comparing with `!=`) makes an assumption that `i` will be incremented only once per iteration. If it skips the value `sequence.length()` then the loop could continue beyond the bounds of the sequence and cause an error.

You can therefore make an argument that the second implementation is more robust: it does not depend on assumptions about whether loop body changes `i` (note: actually it still makes the assumption that `i` is never negative).

To give some motivation for why you might not want to make that assumption, imagine that the loop is scanning a string, doing some text processing. You write the loop and everything is fine. Now your requirements change and you decide you need to support escape characters in the text string, so you change the loop body such that if it detects an escape character (say, backslash), it increments `i` to skip the character immediately following the escape. Now the first loop has a bug because if the last character of the text is backslash, the loop body will increment `i` and the loop will continue on beyond the end of the sequence.

Answer (score -1):

I personally describe a code as 'robust' which has this one, important attributes:

1. If my mom sits in front of it and work with it, she can't break the system

Now, by break I mean either getting the system into an unstable state, or causing an **UNHANDLED** exception. You know, sometimes for a simple concept, you can make a complex definition and explanation. But I'd prefer simple definitions. Users are pretty good at finding robust applications. If the user of your application send you many requests about bugs, about state loss, about unintuitive workflows, etc., then there is something wrong with your programming.